# How to text-indent all input labels within a div?

Tags: css, reactjs

I've got a checkbox (Box 1) that has 2 "sub"-checkboxes (Box 1A, and Box 1B).

```
class Checkboxes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>

        <div>
          <label>
          Box 1
          <input type="checkbox" id="box1" value="box1" />
          </label>
        </div>

        <div style={{textIndent: "5px each-line"}}>
          <label>
          Box 1A
          <input type="checkbox" id="boxA" value="boxA" />
          </label><br/>
          <label>
          Box 1B
          <input type="checkbox" id="boxB" value="boxB" />
          </label><br/>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

For clarity, I'm trying to indent "Box 1A" and  "Box 1B" so that it's visually clear they're directly related to "Box 1".

I've applied  `{{textIndent: "5px each-line"}}` to the entire "sub-checkbox" div to no avail.

Comment: did you try with css class? seems like there some problem with textIndent in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I have worked with your code and you can solve this problem by just giving a marginLeft as 50px Im attaching the code here ! and the link of codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-shirley-uci3v
if this doesn't work then please let me know there are other solutions as well!

```
<div className="App">
  <div style={{ border: "5px solid black" }}>
    <label>
      Box 1
      <input type="checkbox" id="box1" value="box1" />
    </label>
    <div style={{ marginLeft: "50px", border: "5px solid black" }}>
      <label style={{ textIndent: "5px" }}>
        Box 1A
        <input type="checkbox" id="boxA" value="boxA" />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Box 1B
        <input type="checkbox" id="boxB" value="boxB" />
      </label>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```